# iOS using UITableView reloadData vs endUpdates

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data

I am writing an app with a basic `UITableView` that shows `NSManagedObject`s that are loaded from `CoreData`. 
There is also a background process that is running and notifies the `viewController` using `NSNotificationCenter` of any changes to the `CoreData` `NSManagedObject` (IE: Using `NSInserted`/`Updated`/`DeletedObjectsKey`). I have a few questions regarding the best way to update the `tableView` after the view receives the notification of changed data.

1. Is it better to call `reloadData` on the `tableView` or figure out a diff on the data and do the inserts/deletes/updates inside a `tableview.BeginUpdates()` - `tableView endUpdates()`?
2. Is it a valid practice to refresh the `tableView` while a user is interacting with the `tableView`?
3. Is there an easy way that I am missing to do a diff between two arrays of the `CoreData` `NSManagedObject`s and apply to the `tableView`?

I hope I am not overcomplicating things

Comment: Option 4) Use NSFetchedResultsController. It is made exactly for this task.

Comment: Thank you! I will read some docs on this. I am new to iOS development.

Comment: Both the NSFetchedResultsController and the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate documentation has sample code, and there are many tutorials available. – And if you create a new iOS app in Xcode with the "Master-Detail Application" template and select the "Core Data" option then you'll get a sample app with all the boilerplate code for free :)

Comment: Thank you. This makes things much easier than I was making it out to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It depends. If you want just refresh data without any animation then use `reloadData`. In the case when you build up an user-friendly smooth data changing animations, it would be better to calculate the diff and insert/delete rows with some beautiful animation
2. User is not interacting with `tableView` infinitely. You may track when table is not dragging and update the data, but refreshing view to show actual data is common practice today. For example, at the web it is AJAX technology. Also, as I mentioned in 1, use animation to attract user's attention to new data
3. As it mentioned in the comments, in your case using `NSFetchedResultsController` would be better

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I went with option 3 as per @MartinR 's comments